# tkinter, How can you drag across buttons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I have a simple program where when you click a button from a grid it will be filled a colour. I wish to be able to drag across over the buttons and they get filled, unlike at the moment where you have to click every single button. Can this be done?

Here's my code that probably isn't the best:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

grid= Frame(root)
grid.pack()

img0=PhotoImage(file="0.png")
img1=PhotoImage(file="1.png")
img2=PhotoImage(file="2.png")

fill = 1

class button:

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        self.type=0

        self.but=Button(grid,command=self.change, image=img0, borderwidth=0)
        self.but.grid(row=y, column=x)

    def change(self):

        if self.type==fill:
            self.but.config(image=img0)
            self.type=0
        else:
            self.but.config(image=eval("img"+str(fill)))
            self.type=fill

def create(x,y):

    grid_buttons = []

    for Y in range(y):
        grid_buttons.append([])
        for X in range(x):
            grid_buttons[Y].append(button(X, Y))

create(15,15)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could have a container class that holds all the buttons and keeps track of if the mouse has been pressed on one of the buttons. Then the buttons could each bind to the `<Motion>` event. If the mouse is pressed, they change color.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't get that to work. Could you show an example if you have the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

grid= Frame(root)
grid.pack()

img0=PhotoImage(file="0.png")
img1=PhotoImage(file="1.png")
img2=PhotoImage(file="2.png")

fill = 1

class button:

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        self.type=0

        self.but=Button(grid,command=self.change, image=img0, borderwidth=0)
        self.but.grid(row=y, column=x)

        #Changed
        self.already_changed = False

    def change(self):
        if self.type==fill:
            self.but.config(image=img0)
            self.type=0
        else:
            self.but.config(image=eval("img"+str(fill))) #I left this in here, but you should NEVER use eval(). It's unsafe.
            self.type=fill

    #Changed
    def mouse_entered(self):
        if not self.already_changed:
            self.change()
            self.already_changed = True

    def mouse_up(self):
        self.already_changed = False

#Changed
class Container:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        grid_buttons = []

        for Y in range(y):
            grid_buttons.append([])
            for X in range(x):
                grid_buttons[Y].append(button(X, Y))

        self.buttons = grid_buttons
        grid.bind_all("<Button-1>", self.mouse_down)
        grid.bind_all("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.mouse_up)
        grid.bind_all("<B1-Motion>", self.mouse_motion)
        self.mouse_pressed = False

    def mouse_down(self, e):
        self.mouse_pressed = True

    def mouse_up(self, e):
        self.mouse_pressed = False
        for row in self.buttons:
            for but in row:
                but.mouse_up()

    def mouse_motion(self, e):
        for row in self.buttons:
            for but in row:
                if grid.winfo_containing(e.x_root, e.y_root) is but.but:
                    but.mouse_entered()

container = Container(15,15)

root.mainloop()
```

Now, I noticed that some of the things you did aren't quite Python style. So here's a version that more closely follows Python convention. Be warned that it's quite different.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

images = {0: PhotoImage(file="0.png"),
          1: PhotoImage(file="1.png"),
          2: PhotoImage(file="2.png")}

fill = 1

class MyButton(Button): #Convention is for class names to start with uppercase letters
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(master, image = images[0], borderwidth = 0)
        self.type = 0
        self.already_changed = False

    def change(self):
        if self.type == fill:
            self.type = 0
        else:
            self.type = fill
        self.config(image=images[self.type])

    def mouse_entered(self):
        if not self.already_changed:
            self.change()
            self.already_changed = True

    def mouse_up(self):
        self.already_changed = False

class Container(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, width, height):
        super(Container, self).__init__(master)

        buttons = []

        for y in range(height):
            buttons.append([])
            for x in range(width):
                button = MyButton(self)
                button.grid(row = x, column = y)

                buttons[y].append(button)

        self.buttons = buttons

        self.bind_all("<Button-1>", self.mouse_down)
        self.bind_all("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.mouse_up)
        self.bind_all("<B1-Motion>", self.mouse_motion)

        self.mouse_pressed = False

    def mouse_down(self, e):
        self.update_containing_button(e)
        self.mouse_pressed = True

    def mouse_up(self, e):
        self.mouse_pressed = False
        for row in self.buttons:
            for button in row:
                button.mouse_up()

    def mouse_motion(self, e):
        self.update_containing_button(e)

    def update_containing_button(self, e):
        for row in self.buttons:
            for button in row:
                if self.winfo_containing(e.x_root, e.y_root) is button:
                    button.mouse_entered()

grid = Container(root, 15, 15)
grid.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Why post both? Because it looks like you have more code in the actual application (that's good, it's a minimal example). I didn't want to force you to rewrite my code to make it work with the rest of your code, or vice versa.

Functionality differences between the two versions:

- The second version has been modified so it uses object-oriented features instead of global variables, making it more flexible and easier to change.
- The second version removes the binding on the buttons themselves, instead having the container handle everything.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and advise!